# Clarify the ambiguity of partial template specialization

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, specialization

I am confused by the error output of GCC for the partial specializations below.

```cpp
// Primary
template<class T, class U1, class U2, class... Us>
struct S{};

// #1
template<class T, class... Us>
struct S<T, T, T, Us...>{};

// #2
template<class T, class U, class... Us>
struct S<T, T, U, Us...>{};

// #3
template<class T, class U, class... Us>
struct S<T, U, T, Us...>{};

// #4
template<class T, class U1, class U2, class U3, class... Us>
struct S<T, U1, U2, U3, Us...>{};
```

When I tried to call `S<int, int, long, float, double>` the compiler said it could not decide which of #2 and #4 to choose as the one instantiate. But I think #2 is more specialized than #4 regarding this, so it should make a decision.

My reasons are listed below:

When both #2 and #4 could be called, i.e the number of template arguments is no less than 4, from the way introduced [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization#Partial_ordering), we can define a fictitious function for #2 which is

```cpp
template<class T, class U, class... Us>
f<X<T, T, U, Us...>); // #A
```

and one for #4

```cpp
template<class T, class U1, class U2, class U3, class... Us>
f<X<T, U1, U2, U3, Us...>); // #B
```

Then, #A from #B (`void(X<T, T, U, aUs...>)` from `void(X<U1, U2, U3, U4, bUs...>)`):

- `P1=T, A1=U1: T=U1`,
- `P2=T, A2=U2: T=U2: fails`;

and #B from #A (`void(X<T, U1, U2, U3, bUs...>)` from `void(X<U1, U2, U3, aUs...>)`):

- `P1=T, A1=U1`,
- `P2=U1, A2=U2`,
- `P3=U2, A3=U3`,
- `P4=U3, A4=<aUs...>[0]` (`<aUs...>` is not empty in this case),
- `P5=Us..., A5=<aUs...>[1,]` (`<aUs...>[1,]` may be empty now).

So #B from #A is successfully performed in this way, then I think #2 is more specialized than #4 so #2 should be chosen.

If GCC is right (most possible), I would like to know which part of my above statements goes wrong. Thanks very much.

A live example could be found [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Eq6jTc49K).

Comment: The actual (rather complicated) rules aside, why would you consider #B more specialized if it can't be called with argument lists which #A can be called with? (specifically argument lists of length 3)

Comment: Neither is more specialized than the other. Roughly, #2 says "use me when the first two arguments are the same type", and #4 says "use me when there are at least four arguments" (the primary template accepts three or more). Then there's an ambiguity when there are four or more arguments, and the first two are the same type.

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry for not having put it clear. I meant to mention that #4 is not considered when argument number is less than 4, other than to think #2 is more specialized because #4 is not called sometimes. And all statements afterwards are based on the case that both #2 and #4 would match. Fixed it.

Comment: Btw. I meant "less specialized" in my first comment.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So my way of comparing their specialization is wrong when used here. And it should only be used when they accepts the same number of non-variadic  template arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conceptually neither `#2` nor `#4` is more specialized, because there are lists of template arguments for `A` such that `#2` is viable, but not `#4`, as well as such sets for which `#4` is viable, but `#2` is not.

In your formal analysis everything looks correct, except that at

> `P4=U3, A4=<aUs...>[0]` (`<aUs...>` is not empty in this case),

deduction fails, because you need to actually compare all of `<aUs...>` as a single (imagined) template argument `A4` to be matched against `P4` and per [[temp.deduct.type]#9.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.deduct.type#9.2), because it originated from a pack expansion, `A4` should then have either no corresponding element in the template argument list of the parameter or correspond to an element of the parameter's template argument list that also originated from a pack expansion, which `P4` does not (since it is just `U3`).

Answer (score 2):

**For anyone who may meet the same problem.**

The accepted answer referred to the WP and the rules underlying. In comments there are also straight-forward ones that clarify how #2 and #4 are *incomparable* w.r.t partial specialization.

If you have to write programs like this and get stuck here, read ahead.

<s>(By saying a specialization *response*s, I intend to mean that it matches.</s> (*response* should be *respond*)

As stated in the accepted answer and comment, for a given case `S<int, int, long, float, double>`, we have to choose which one of #2 and #4 to match. So we have to rewrite #2 (and #4) so that they do **not** conflict.

#1, #2, #3 **only** depends on the first three template arguments, and the `class... Us` easily makes them candidates for #4 mistakenly. So we remove it from their template header, i.e.

```cpp
// #1
template<class T>
struct S<T, T, T> {};

// #2
template<class T, class U>
struct S<T, T, U> {};

// #3
template<class T, class U>
struct S<T, U, T> {};
```

After the rewriting, we have eliminated the conflict between #4 and the other 3, so the compiler would not complain about many candidates. For instantiation like `S<int, int, long, float, double>`, since it has 5 template arguments, #4 is the one to match.

But what if we would like #2 to match?

We have to rewrite #4 in the following way. #2 takes **only** 3 template arguments, so we could pass the `<T, U1, U2>` in #4's template header to #2 and make it **derive** from #2, i.e.

```cpp
template <class T, class U1, class U2, class U3, class... Us>
struct S<T, U1, U2, U3, Us...>: public S<T, U1, U2> {}
```

In this way, for the given case, #2 would match. However, #4 will just **degrades** to a case which accepts 4 or more template arguments for #0~#3. i.e. `S<int, long, float, double, int>` now matches #0.

If that is **not** expected (we just want #0 to be a primary and work **only** when the number of template arguments is 3), to solve this we could use `std::conditional`, i.e.

```cpp
template <class T, class U1, class U2, class U3, class... Us>
struct S<T, U1, U2, U3, Us...>: public std::conditional_t<bool(S<T, U1, U2>::value), S<T, U1, U2>, S4> {}
```

We have to make sure #0 has an static member `value` which evaluates to `false` and define another helper class `S4` though.

---

A live example that checks whether the first template argument `T` is in the template list `U1, U2, Us...` could be found at [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/ab6rvc7vY). (It is inspired by the possible implementation of `std::disjunction` provided [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/disjunction))

Comment: I don't think the word "response" means what you think it means (e.g. it's not a verb). Did you mean "match"? or "is chosen"?

Comment: @Sneftel I have not noticed that until you point it out. I should use "respond" XD, anyway I will change them to "match".